# My C++ program gets slower as computation proceeds

Tags: c++, neural-network

I wrote a neural network program in C++ to test something, and I found that my **program gets slower as computation proceeds**. Since this kind of phenomenon is somewhat I've never seen before, I checked possible causes. Memory used by program did not change when it got slower. RAM and CPU status were fine when I ran the program.

Fortunately, the previous version of the program did not have such problem. So I finally found that a single statement that makes the program slow. The program does not get slower when I use this statement:

```
dw[k][i][j] = hidden[k-1][i].y * hidden[k][j].phi;
```

However, the program gets slower and slower as soon as I replace above statement with:

```
dw[k][i][j] = hidden[k-1][i].y * hidden[k][j].phi - lambda*w[k][i][j];
```

To solve this problem, I did my best to find and remove the cause but I failed... The below is the simple code structure. For the case that this is not the problem that is related to local statement, I uploaded my code to google drive. The URL is located at the end of this question.

**MLP.h**

```
    class MLP
    {
    private:
    ...
    double lambda;
    double ***w;
    double ***dw;
    neuron **hidden;
    ...
```

**MLP.cpp**

```
    ...
    for(k = n_depth - 1; k > 0; k--)
    {
        if(k == n_depth - 1)
            ...
        else
        {
            ...
            for(j = 1; n_neuron > j; j++)
            {
                for(i = 0; n_neuron > i; i++)
                {
                    //dw[k][i][j] = hidden[k-1][i].y * hidden[k][j].phi;
                    dw[k][i][j] = hidden[k-1][i].y * hidden[k][j].phi - lambda*w[k][i][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ...
```

Full source code: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1A8Uw0hNDADp3-3VWAgO4eTtj4sVk_LZh

Comment: You will have to provide a [mcve], and never link to code.

Comment: Probably getting cache misses due to the last expression (w[k][i][j]) that you weren't getting with [k][i].  Depends on the size of the arrays and their elements.

Comment: Thank you Passer By and Robinson! I did not know that it can be a problem to write link to code. I'm going to change the program structure to cache friendly structure as possible. Thank you once again. Good day guys

Comment: I doubt that cache will make it slower and slower. Have you checked whether you get overflow or very small (denormalized numbers)?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly why it gets slower and slower, but I do see where you can gain some performance.

> Two and higher dimensional arrays are still stored in one dimensional
>   memory. This means (for C/C++ arrays) `array[i][j]` and `array[i][j+1]`
>   are adjacent to each other, whereas `array[i][j]` and `array[i+1][j]` may
>   be arbitrarily far apart.

> Accessing data in a more-or-less sequential fashion, as stored in
>   physical memory, can dramatically speed up your code (sometimes by an
>   order of magnitude, or more)!

> When modern CPUs load data from main memory into processor cache,
>   they fetch more than a single value.  Instead they fetch a block of
>   memory containing the requested data and adjacent data (a cache line
>   ). This means after `array[i][j]` is in the CPU cache, `array[i][j+1]` has
>   a good chance of already being in cache, whereas `array[i+1][j]` is
>   likely to still be in main memory.

Source: https://people.cs.clemson.edu/~dhouse/courses/405/papers/optimize.pdf

With your current code, `w[k][i][j]` will be read, and on the next iteration, `w[k][i+1][j]` will be read. You should invert i and j so that `w` is read in sequential order:

```
for(j = 1; n_neuron > j; ++j)
{
    for(i = 0; n_neuron > i; ++i)
    {
        dw[k][j][i] = hidden[k-1][j].y * hidden[k][i].phi - lambda*w[k][j][i];
    }
}
```

Also note that `++x` should be slightly faster than `x++`, since `x++` has to create a temporary containing the old value of `x` as the expression result. The compiler might optimize it when the value is unused though, but do not count on it.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. As you commented, I managed to make my program little bit faster.